# R multiple regular expressions, dataframe column names

Tags: r, dataframe, filter

I have a dataframe `data` with a lot of columns in the form of

```
  ...v1...min ...v1...max ...v2...min ...v2...max
1       a           a           a           a
2       b           b           b           b
3       c           c           c           c
```

where in place `...` there could be any expression.

I would like to create a function `createData` that takes three arguments:

- `X`: a dataframe,
- `cols`: a vector containing first part of the column, so i.e. `c("v1", "v2")`
- `fun`: a vector containing second part of the column, so i.e. `c("min")`, or `c("max", "min")`

and returns filtered dataframe, so - for example:

`createData(X, c("v1"), None)` would return this kind of dataframe:

```
  ...v1...min ...v1...max 
1       a           a    
2       b           b  
3       c           c
```

while `createData(X, c("v1", "v2"), c("min"))` would give me

```
  ...v1...min ...v2...min 
1       a           a    
2       b           b  
3       c           c
```

At this point I decided I need to use i.e. `select(contains())` from `dplyr` package.

```
createData <- function(data, fun, cols)
{
  X %>% select(contains())
  return(X)
}
```

What I struggle with is:

- how to filter columns that consist two (or maybe more?) strings, i.e. both `var1` and `min`? I tried going with `data[grepl(".*(v1*min|min*v1).*", colnames(data), ignore.case=TRUE)]` but it doesn't seem to work and also my expressions aren't fixed - they depend on the vector I pass,
- how to filter multiple columns with different names, i.e. `c("v1", "v2")`, passed in a vector? and how to combine it with the first question?

I don't really need to stick with `dplyr` package, it was just for the sake of the example. Thanks!

**EDIT**:

An reproducible example:

```
data = data.frame(AXv1c2min = c(1,2,3),
           subv1trwmax = c(4,5,6),
           ss25v2xxmin = c(7,8,9),
           cwfv2urttmmax = c(10,11,12))
```

Comment: You may need `matches` if we want to pass a regex.  It is better to provide a reproducible example i.e. without the `...`

Comment: @akrun you are right, I just didn't want to bedim the whole picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass a vector to `contains`, it will function like an OR tag, while multiple `select` statements will have additive effects. So for your esample data:

We can filter for `(v1 OR v2) AND min` like this:

```
library(tidyverse)

data %>%
    select(contains(c('v1','v2'))) %>%
    select(contains('min'))

  AXv1c2min ss25v2xxmin
1         1           7
2         2           8
3         3           9
```

So as a function where either argument is optional:

```
createData <- function(data, fun=NULL, cols=NULL) {
    if (!is.null(fun)) data <- select(data, contains(fun))
    if (!is.null(cols)) data <- select(data, contains(cols))
    return(data)
}
```

A series of examples:

```
createData(data, cols=c('v1', 'v2'), fun='min')
  AXv1c2min ss25v2xxmin
1         1           7
2         2           8
3         3           9

createData(data, cols=c('v1'))
  AXv1c2min subv1trwmax
1         1           4
2         2           5
3         3           6

createData(data, fun=c('min'))
  AXv1c2min ss25v2xxmin
1         1           7
2         2           8
3         3           9

createData(data, cols=c('v1'), fun=c('min', 'max'))
  AXv1c2min subv1trwmax
1         1           4
2         2           5
3         3           6

createData(data, cols=c('v1'), fun=c('max'))
  subv1trwmax
1           4
2           5
3           6
```